# Warning: Undefined variable $conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventario\

Tags: php, mysql, azure

Cuando entro al dashboard de mí página de forma de local todo se muestra correctamente, pero cuando subí mi página aún host como en Azure Microsoft, este no me despliega los queries correctamente, me muestra errores en todos los queries así como se muestra:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
> in... {main} thrown in...

Ejemplo de uno de mis queries:

```
  $qry = $conn->query("SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) as pending FROM tickets t 
    where not status=2 group by t.id");
```

db_connect.php

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_init(); mysqli_ssl_set($conn,NULL,NULL,
"/Inventory/DigiCert.crt.pem", NULL, NULL); 
mysqli_real_connect($conn "inventario-db.mysql.database.azure.com", "admin", "pass", 
"inventario", 3306, 
MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);

if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn)) {
  die('Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

admin_class.php

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Class Action {
  private $db;

public function __construct() {
    ob_start();
include 'db_connect.php';

$this->db = $conn;
}
function __destruct() {
    $this->db->close();
    ob_end_flush();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: estas ejecutando la misma version de php con las mismas extensiones?

Comment: edita tu post, he incliye el error completo y la linea de codigo en la que se descto asi como donde citas el archivo db_connect.php

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Asi es

Comment: Cuando llamas a `mysqli_real_connect()` ¿No te falta una coma después de `$conn`?.

Comment: El error te indica que llamas al método ->query en un objeto null. Esto es, por alguna razón, en ese momento $conn es un nulo. Te diría que revises bien el mysqli_ssl_set, porque indicas un certificado en la raíz del servidor, y no en la raíz de tu proyecto.